# Advantage and use of Apache James Mail Server?

Tags: java, apache, email, james

As i am implementing a web application for User management i need to send 1k email daily,one way to use some paid email service but i want to implement my own ,will Apache James Mail server will help me can i send mail through it or i have to buy some paid services for this? I want to know Apache James mail server can be implemented easily and send mail like we are sending though Gmail or Yahoo?

I was reading below inks

[Working with James, Part 1: An introduction to Apache's James enterprise e-mail server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-james1/)

[Configuring Apache JAMES as LiveCycle’s Mail Server](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2008/10/configuring_apache_james_as_li.html)

But not very clear anyone can exaplin ? My concern is ,If we any Such Server is available why to go for paid services .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ensuring that Big Providers (like: Yahoo, Gmail, Hotmail) accepts email sent from your server. Email Deliverability issues are the reason why people tends to buy a paid services.

If you setup own mail server, you must consider at least:

- Setup mail daemon for receiving and sending (like Apache James)
- Setup DNS related things like SPF, DKIM, PTR-record, etc
- Rate limited sending, some provider doesn't like when you throw 1000 email at once.
- Bounce management (e.g. you must stop delivering email to dead account)
- Spam/Virus Filtering (you don't want to receiving too many spam)

**Note:** Paid services may added several facilities like nice Statistics Dashboard.

Comment: So for a web application where we have to send 1K mail daily which will better paid or own setup?

Comment: If you have time AND person to initial_setup/maintenance that mail server, you can choose own setup. My apps currently sent 10k email daily to big providers. At first three month, I was struggling to ensure that my email doesn't end to spam folder. So, I agree with this sentences from Kayaman answer "It's a tradeoff between time and money."

Comment: So it is clear we can setup our own mail server but it may be challenged for us our mail go to Spam Folder and we have to take care other things as well thats why people prefer paid services

Comment: Yes, you can focus to your apps instead building a 'correct` mail server

Answer (score 2):

A mail server is a mail server. If you use JavaMail, you just need to have a properly configured mail server running somewhere, and use it. Some widely used (linux) mail servers are `sendmail` and `postfix`, don't know if you'll get any advantage out of using `James`.

As for why go for paid services? Some people don't know how to set up a mail server and they will rather pay for these services than spend their own time trying to set one up. It's a tradeoff between time and money.

Comment: Thanks for Your Update So do you mean if We will Able to setup James kind of project We do not need to buy Paid Services And from our web application we can send mail like we can do with paid services